# How can I access to a "parent" protected member?

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is a "simulation" of my [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fe8e9312f1f798f):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    int test = 10;
};

class C;

class B : public A
{
private:
    C *c;

public:
    B();

};

class C
{
public:
    C(B *b) {
        cout << b->test;
    }
};

B::B() {
    c = new C(this);
}  

int main()
{
    B();
}
```

I can't touch the `protected` status type of that `test` variable, since is from another Framework and I don't have real "access".

I need to create an instance of class C from B (which extend A), passing B to it and access (from C) to the param `test` of A.

Is there a fancy way for doing it? Within B I can use test without any problem...

Comment: add a `int getTest(){ return test;}` in `B`.

Comment: As mush as I hate getters and setter you can just define a public getter in `B` that returns a reference to the `A` member.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C class doesn't inherit from B, so B is not a parent, so the C class has no access to the protected members.

**Workaround**

If you control B and C but are not allowed to touch A which comes from another framework,  you could try:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    C *c;

public:
    B();
friend C;  // Make C a friend of B so that it has access.  
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/vnj1mF)

**Advise**

Despite there is a technical workaround to achieve what you want, it might not be advisable to do so.   The idea of protected members is that it's implementation details only relevant to derived classes.  By opening it with a friendship, you create a dependency to implementation details you are not supposed to have access to.  So you'd violate the framework's design principle.  Possible but at your own risk.

Another approach could be to add a public getter to the protected element in B and then in C refer to this public member ([demo](http://ideone.com/gzpczp)).  It's better but you'd still expose data that you're not supposed to.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a public accessor in B:

```
class B : public A
{
private:
    C *c;

public:
    B();
    int get_test() const { return this->test; }
};
```